# Maximum call stack size exceeded - know why (too many functions) but how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack-overflow, chaining

On my page I have a simple piece of code based on nested functions, which helps me to show one elements after another in right order:

```
        var fade = 700;
        $('#s2icon-center').fadeIn(fade, function() {
            $('#s2icon-1').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                $('#s2icon-3, #s2icon-9').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                    $('#s2icon-6, #s2icon-11, #s2icon-17').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                        $('#s2icon-5, #s2icon-14, #s2icon-19').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                            $('#s2icon-8, #s2icon-13, #s2icon-22').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                                $('#s2icon-2, #s2icon-16, #s2icon-21').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                                    $('#s2icon-4, #s2icon-10, #s2icon-24').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                                        $('#s2icon-7, #s2icon-12, #s2icon-18').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                                            $('#s2icon-15, #s2icon-20').fadeIn(fade, function() {
                                                $('#s2icon-23').fadeIn(fade);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

But in my opinion, because of using too many functions in one place, page is getting laggy and I get an error in console: 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Now my question to you guys is, how (in most easy way) can I get same effect but more productive?

Thanks in advance!

------------- EDIT

Here how it's should look:
[Codepen Full view](http://cdpn.io/dLIwK)

And the code is right here:
[Codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/zyziu/pen/imqLH)

Comment: please create jsFiddle for your code

Comment: Done, I'he add codepen demo to my post :)

Comment: Wow, that looks like a bug in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) which delays execution of the next function in chain by a specified amount of time.

```
var fade = 700;

// ID's of all elements you want to fade
var elems = ["#d1", "#d2", "#d3", "#d4", "#d5"];
// In your case:
// var elems = ['#s2icon-center', '#s2icon-1', '#s2icon-3, #s2icon-9', '#s2icon-6, #s2icon-11, #s2icon-17']; // and so on...

// Loop over all those elements
for (var e = 0; e < elems.length; e += 1) {
    // Get element by it's ID (from the array)
    var element = $(elems[e]);

    // Use .delay() to delay execution of fade by the amount
    // "fade * e", so 0, 700, 1400, ...
    element.delay(fade * e).fadeOut(fade);    
}
```

(note I've used `fadeOut()` to keep example clear - you'll need to change it to `fadeOut()`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HrzdP/1).

Comment: Yes, this will work if I have to show elements in order, one after another -  1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 > ...
But in this case, I have to show those elements in different order - 1 > 2 > 4 and 9 > 3 and 5 and 7 > ...

This should simulate a random fadeIn (but it's not a random each time). And all elements are in a circle - a have to show elements placed in few radius rows.
I will try to make some fiddle with this.

Comment: As long as you're fading one element at a time, it's only a matter of correctly specifying `elems` array. In your case it would be something like: `['#s2icon-center', '#s2icon-1', '#s2icon-3, #s2icon-9', ...]`. Then, of course, in a loop you'd not use ID's but this selectors. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've add a demo and my full code on my first post. You can check it what I have to achieve :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: omg.. I'm so dumb.. ^^, Yes, it's exactly that what I was looking for.. And all I needed to do was put few ID elems into one array position in your previous code! Thank you very much - I will be wiser from now on :)

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to have a problem with is the [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback:

> `Complete Function`
>
> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If
>   multiple elements are animated, **the callback is executed once per
>   matched element**, not once for the animation as a whole.

That's not what you want. Instead, use [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), which should also prevent the stack overflow.

```
var fade = 700;
$('#s2icon-center').fadeIn(fade).promise().then(function() {
    return $('#s2icon-1').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-3, #s2icon-9').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-6, #s2icon-11, #s2icon-17').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-5, #s2icon-14, #s2icon-19').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-8, #s2icon-13, #s2icon-22').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-2, #s2icon-16, #s2icon-21').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-4, #s2icon-10, #s2icon-24').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-7, #s2icon-12, #s2icon-18').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-15, #s2icon-20').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    return $('#s2icon-23').fadeIn(fade).promise();
}).then(function() {   
    console.log("all finished");
});
```

Comment: I get it. Then I have to read about those promises (I will be honest, I don't know them yet) because they seem to be quite usefull :)
Btw. Do you think this solution is more productive than using a for loop and array (solution above)? What's the recommendation to use often? 
Thank you

Comment: You could (should) concert my solution to use an array as well, to reduce the boilerplate overhead. Not using `delay` like above but promises will properly chain the actions, asserting they don't overlap even with timing interferences. Honestly, your nested callback code shouldn't have produced a stack overflow as well :-)